# How to convert string to datetime as column header

Tags: google-colaboratory

I currently have a database that is a time series but instead of a actual time for the header of each column in just gives me Period_1, Period_2 ect.

How do I Rename all of these column headers but also convert them to datetimes in seconds starting from 0 - whatever number?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you'd want column headers as the actual dates. That doesn't seem like it is any sort of Time Series Database with which I'm familiar. Typically a timestamp (as a data type) is a column. Not a column for each distinct timestamp. That way madness lies.

For a good example of a time series database, check out [QuestDB](https://questdb.io/?ref=davidgsiot)